# HttpContext.Current.Request.Url How to get the part after application name from URL

Tags: c#, asp.net

```
var myPath = HttpContext.Current.Request.Url.AbsolutePath;

// output: myApplication/myFolder/myPage.aspx

var pageName = Path.GetFileName(myPath);

//output: myPage.aspx
```

I am trying to output  "**myFolder/myPage.aspx**" without the application path.

Is there built-in option to return that or I would need to use regular expression to get what I need?

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

You should be able to make use of `HttpContext.Current.Request.Url.Segments` and then a simple string concat:

```
String[] segments = HttpContext.Current.Request.Url.Segments;
string result = segments[1] + segments[2];
```

or instead of string concat, use: `string result = Path.Combine(segments[1],segments[2]);`

Answer (score 0):

This should work

```
public ActionResult oihoi(string ImageName
{
string _FileName = Path.GetFileName(ImageName.FileName);

string folderpath = "UploadedFiles/WebGallery";

string path = Server.MapPath("~/" + folderpath);

string firstsegment = "";
}
```